# Are round pcb edges useful?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

I am new to PCB layouts, and some of the layouts I've seen have round edges copper pours and or round edges boards.
Is that useful from the point of view of signal integrity or is it purely aesthetic?

Comment: Most likely just aesthetic, but you’d need to show an example if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: Round edges on boards is useful if the board fits in a milled recess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are useful but it is unknown if it applies to your specific PCB.

For high voltage potentials, you do want to avoid sharp edges to prevent arcing.

And for controlled breakdown, you can even do spark gap PCB patterns.